# How to properly reuse Animation in Android?

Tags: android, animation, view

I'm trying to reuse AlphaAnimation object in a method of an Activity for every new MyView added every second to myLayout:

```
private AlphaAnimation showAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);

private void addViewAndAnimate() {
    MyView view = new MyView();
    myLayout.addView(view);
    showAnimation.setDuration(durationTime);
    view.startAnimation(showAnimation);
}
```

but after I call addViewAndAnimate() the animation is not applied for latest added MyView only, but gets repeated for all MyViews added earlier.

Are view objects somehow bound to an animation? If so is there a way to detach them?

Comment: use ObjectAnimator instead of AlphaAnimation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove animation from the `View`, use `View.clearAnimation();`
So you need to store somewhere a view, to which the animation is applied before, and clear it before applying it to new view. Also you can try to create a new Animation instance for each view.
Or start animation in `Handler.post()`. This shouldstart animation in the current view for sure

Comment: I solved the situation by creating new Animation for each View, which seemed the easiest way in my case.
So if View animation needs clearing or recreating that also answers my question that Animation object is bound to View object.